# When to use merge vs update in case of detached entity

Tags: hibernate, merge

```
public class unconnected {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.out.println("enter the id you want toc carry change on");
        //Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        //int id=s.nextInt();
        dao x=new dao();
    emp e=  x.findbyid(id);
        e.setId(10);
        e.setName("dsfsdassafasdsa");
        e.setJob("546");
        e.setSalary(789);
        x.update(e);
        }

public class dao {
    public emp findbyid(int id)
    {
    Session session=myfactory.getSession();
    emp e=(emp)session.get(emp.class, id);
    session.close();
    return e;
    }
    public void update(emp e)
    {
    Session session=myfactory.getSession();
    Transaction t=session.beginTransaction();
    session.merge(e);
    t.commit();
    session.close();

    }


}
```

now my question is that if i use in update session.update(e) it works too,it also updates the value in database,so how would i know that when to use merge and when to use update in case of detached entity

Answer (score 0):

Merge should be used when you have 2 detached objects representing the same entity. Hibernate will automatically determine which fields were updated last and merge the two objects together so that the most up to date information is present in the new object which is then added to the database.

Update should be used when you simply want to update your database object with you detached entity.

Ex:
`Foo1` and `Foo2` are both `Foo` Object which have fields `Bar1` and `Bar2`. `Foo1`'s value of `Bar1` was updated after `Foo2`'s value of `Bar1`. When you call merge, `Foo1`'s value of `Bar1` will be used to update the database instance of `Foo`.